# Verifying a large directory after copy from one hard drive to another

Tags: files, copy, checksums

I have a home file server that I use Ubuntu on.

Recently, one of my drives filled up so I got another and threw it in there.

I have a very large folder, the directory is about 1.7 T in size and contains a decent amount of files.

I used [GCP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gcp.1.html) to COPY the files from the old drive to the new one and it seems to have worked fine.

I want to now validate the new directory on the new drive against the original directory on the old drive before I delete the data from the old drive to free up space. I understand that I can do a CRC check to do this.

How, specifically, can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `md5sum`:

```
cd /path/to/old/data
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > MD5SUMS
mv MD5SUMS /path/to/new/data
cd /path/to/new/data
md5sum -c < MD5SUMS
```

This would take a long time, considering you have 1.7TB of data, just like every other verification method.

Comment: Maybe you can add alternatives with `CRC` and alike, if users don't need cryptography, it would complete much faster.

Comment: on a 22GB test, using md5sum is faster. So no crc32 version.